# PostgreSQL: How do I have my function return the id of the new row I inserted?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-function

I'm new to sql

This is my error

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_add_reimbursement_ticket( f_employee text, f_amount decimal, f_request_type text, f_description text )
    RETURNS int as 
$id_num$
  DECLARE 
      id_num int = null; 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT username FROM employee WHERE username = f_employee; 
      IF NOT FOUND THEN 
          id_num := -1; 
      else 
          SET id_num TO (INSERT INTO reimbursement_ticket (employee, amount, request_type, description)
       VALUES (f_employee, f_amount, f_request_type, f_description) RETURNING id); 
      END IF; 
  RETURN (id_num); 
END;
$id_num$ 
LANGAUGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. First `LANGAUGE` needs to be `LANGUAGE`.

Variables [are assigned](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) using `:=`, not `set`.

But if you want to store the result of a query into a variable, you need to use the [INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) clause.

The result of a SELECT must be stored somewhere. If you don't want that, you need to use [perform](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT). Alternatively you can just use `if not exists`

Putting that all together, the function should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_add_reimbursement_ticket( f_employee text, f_amount decimal, f_request_type text, f_description text )
    RETURNS int 
as 
$id_num$
DECLARE 
  id_num int; 
BEGIN 
  if not exists (select * FROM employee WHERE username = f_employee) then
    return -1;
  end if;

  INSERT INTO reimbursement_ticket (employee, amount, request_type, description)
  VALUES (f_employee, f_amount, f_request_type, f_description) 
  RETURNING id into id_num;

  RETURN id_num; 
END;
$id_num$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Makes a lot of sense. I appreciate your explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
create or replace function func_add_reimbursement_ticket( 
    f_employee     text, 
    f_amount       decimal, 
    f_request_type text, 
    f_description  text
)
returns int as $id_num$
declare
    id_num int = null;
begin
    
    insert into reimbursement_ticket (employee, amount, request_type, description)
    select *
    from (values (f_employee, f_amount, f_request_type, f_description)) 
        as v(employee, amount, request_type, description)
    where exists (select 1 from employee where username = v.employee)
    returning id into id_num;
  
    return id_num;
    
end; 
$id_num$ language plpgsql;
```

Rationale:

- this fixes the syntax glitch, especially on the variable assignment
- an optimization is to move the existence check on the employee directly to the `insert` query, using `exists`; if the employee does not exists, nothing is inserted, and the function returns `null`

Here is a **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fb1fd424cc9f93b979d7e931aa1978f1)** that demonstrates how the function works.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to look into this more. It's a little confusing. I'm familiar with oop languages but not sql. Definitely trying to learn though. Thanks for your help :)